# Slice an array into 4 other arrays

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I have an array which I want to slice in 4 other arrays because I want to display the content of the first array on four columns.

I have tried the code above, but what I get is N columns with 4 items.

```
$groups = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu); $i += 4) $groups[] = array_slice($menu, $i, 4);
```

Can this be modified in order to get exactly 4 columns and distribute the values so they fit?

Comment: See [`array_chunk()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking, could you rephrase the question?

Comment: Let's say I want to split an array into 4 other arrays.

Comment: @Psyche  Something like this : http://codepad.viper-7.com/kwqbB6

Comment: About this part: "...because I want to display the content of the first array on four columns...".  If you want to display your array in a grid, there are much better ways.

Comment: @Baba, not quite. I want to have exactly 4 arrays, or in your example, only 4 <li></li> groups.

Comment: @Psyche see answer ... combing array_chunk and array_slice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Michael Berkowski suggested:

```
$groups = array_chunk($menu,4);
```

Should give you what you need. If you're more into *"manual labour"*:

```
$groups = array();
while($groups[] = array_splice($menu,0,4))
{//no need for any code here ^^ chunks the array just fine
    printf('This loop will run another %d times<br/>',(int)ceil(count($menu)/4));
}
```

*Update:*

I see I got this a bit wrong... want to chunk into 4 arrays, not into arrays of four:

```
$groups = array_chunk($menu,(int)ceil(count($menu)/4));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
// Some Random array
$array = range(1, 20);

// Split it 4 Chuncks
$array = array_chunk($array, 4);

// Slice The first 4 Chunks
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 4);

// Output Result
foreach ( $array as $set ) {
    printf("<li>%s</li>", implode(",", $set));
}
```