# Split an Array into 3 arrays

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slice an array into 4 other arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876333/slice-an-array-into-4-other-arrays)

An array can be split into 3 smaller arrays using:

```
$things = array('...');    // an array containing 9 things
$things = array_chunk($things, count($things)/3);
```

**Problem:** However when `count($things)` the number of items in the array cannot be divided equally by `3`, I end up with **4** smaller arrays. Example, if I have 10 elements in array `$things`, inputting it into `array_chunk()` gives me 3 arrays of 3 elements, and a 4th array containing 1 element.

How can I divide an array into 3 smaller arrays, such that if I have a situation like in the example above, I will end up with

```
count($things[0]) == 4
count($things[1]) == 4
count($things[2]) == 2
```

Bascially what I am doing is to take a big array and display it as equally as possible into 3 columns. It's alphabetically sorted, so sequence is important.

Comment: Round the `$n/3` up, using `ceil()` for example.

Comment: Thanks mario it works! I believe mario answered it first :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `ceil(count($things) / 3)`, so the split point is rounded up. that'd give you (say) 4/4/3 instead of 3/3/3/2 for an 11-item array.

Answer (score 3):

Check the answer I gave on this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876333/slice-an-array-into-4-other-arrays/12876477#12876477), and change `4` to `3`:

```
$groups = array_chunk($all,(int)ceil(count($all)/3));
```