# How to separate an array every x members?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to separate an array every 3 members and put them into different arrays

```
$array = array("hi", "hello", "sup", "example", "something", "ksikikikfr", "frefre");

$output1 = array("hi", "hello", "sup");
$output2 = array("example", "something", "ksikikikfr");
$output3 = array("frefre");
```

This is what I want to get, thanks in advance

Comment: `array_chunk` function.

Comment: `array_chunk()` The manual [is always a good place to look for PHP builtin functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split an Array into 3 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110876/split-an-array-into-3-arrays)

Comment: ...of course not an exact duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create chunks with a size of 3 with [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 3);
print_r($chunks);
```

Comment: We really need a close option for _To lazy to look at the manual._ :) But I guess a bit of low hanging fruit now and again is nice to have :) :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, I need this option too(

Comment: I searched the manual, I thought that function diveded the array into chunks no matter the size of it. But thanks :)